# How to identify the flavour of linux using uname -a or lsb_release -a commands?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, uname

I am new to unix. I just want to check the flavour of my linux machine and tried the below commands

```
[root@ab-l13-i05 jetty-license]# uname -a
Linux ab-l13-i05 2.6.18-128.el5 #1 SMP Wed Jan 21 08:45:05 EST 2009 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

[root@ab-l13-i05 jetty-license]#  lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-3.1-amd64:core-3.1-ia32:core-3.1-noarch:graphics-3.1-amd64:graphics-3.1-ia32:graphics-3.1-noarch
Distributor ID: EnterpriseEnterpriseServer
Description:    Enterprise Linux Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Carthage)
Release:        5.3
Codename:       Carthage
```

So from above the flavour of linux is 'Red Hat Enterprise Linux' or any other?

Comment: `cat /etc/*-release`. Also, see http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-distribution-name-version-number/

Answer (score 2):

cat /etc/issue shows you the name of the OS installed.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: Not really. It sometimes does, but can also be modified by the administrator. From `man issue`: `The file /etc/issue is a text file which contains a message or system identification to be printed before the login prompt.`